# How to add background-color to text navigation on image slider?

Tags: slider, gallery, highlight

I have an image slider that is controlled by text navigation. The text is highlighted orange when it's relative slide is current in the gallery. I would like the other text to have an inactive state with a black background but cannot get this to work!

(In case that didn't make much sense! Basically, I want background-color orange when current, background-color black when inactive.) THANKS

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.slider').each(function(e){
        if(e == 0){
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
         $(this).attr('id', 'handle' + e);
    })

    $('.tabs li').each(function(e){
        if(e == 0){
            $(this).addClass('current'); //adds class current to 1st li
        }
        $(this).wrapInner('<a class="title"></a>'); //wraps list items in anchor tag                
        $(this).children('a').attr('href', '#handle' + e);//adds href to the anchors    
        t = $(this).children('a').text(); 
        $('#handle' + e).append('<h2>' + t + '</h2>'); //adds h2 and text to big images 

    })

    $('.tabs li a').click(function(){
        c = $(this).attr('href');       
        if($(c).hasClass('current')){
            return false;
        }else{
            showImage($(c), 20);
            $('.tabs li').removeClass('current');
            $(this).parent().addClass('current');
            return false;
        }           
    })

    runRotateImages();

    $("#featured").hover(
        function(){                 
            clearTimeout(xx);
        }, 
        function(){                 
            runRotateImages();
        }
    )



})

function showImage(img, duration){       

    $('.slider').removeClass('current').css({
            "opacity" : 0.0, 
            "zIndex" : 2
            });
    img.animate({opacity:1.0}, duration, function(){        
        $(this).addClass('current').css({zIndex:1});
    });  

}
function rotateImages(){

    var curPhoto = $("div.current");
    var nxtPhoto = curPhoto.next();     
    var curTab = $(".tabs li.current");
    var nxtTab = curTab.next();             

    if (nxtPhoto.length == 0) {
        nxtPhoto = $('#featured div:first');    
        nxtTab = $('.tabs li:first-child');         
    }                   

    curTab.removeClass('current');
    nxtTab.addClass('current');
    showImage(nxtPhoto, 300);

}
function runRotateImages(){

    xx = setInterval("rotateImages()", 5000);

}
```

I have added a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n5EPM/3/

However, on jsfiddle it does not seem to automatically cycle through the images, not sure why, have no problems in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using not() method: http://api.jquery.com/not/

Basically, you need to create a new class `disabled`

```
.disabled{
    background-color:#000000;   
}
```

Then, add the following line to your tabs.li's each loop:

```
 $(".tabs li").not(".current").addClass('disabled'); //add disabled class for non-current tabs
```

At last you need to remove disabled class in the rotateimage() function before assigning current and then disable non-current again. like this:

```
curTab.removeClass('current');
nxtTab.removeClass('disabled'); //remove diabled class
nxtTab.addClass('current');
 $(".tabs li").not(".current").addClass('disabled'); // disable non-current again
```

Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n5EPM/9/

This might not be the perfect solution but you will need to tweak it a little bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: no that doesn't work for me! hmmmmm. I have added a jsfiddle @Learner

Comment: because you are using list (li tag), try: $(".tabs li").not(".current").css("background-color", "black");

Comment: no I know that lol I replaced the "div" with ".tabs li" - still doesn't work @Learner

Comment: Sorry something really strange is happening, I swore it was working but I've just gone back to it and it doesn't work. Neither does your jsfiddle. It fails when you click, and the images don't move with the highlighted text. Could you check your jsfiddle again just to see if it's something wrong my end? Thank you! @Learner

Comment: You need to apply same code to click event of the tab link. I wrote the code for auto rotation for the images. Just copy paste the code to click event.